# request madness in node js

Tags: node.js, request

When I run the following command in node:

```
request({
  "method": "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8044/aut",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({secret: "danzellovestodance"})
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("test"); console.log(response.body);
  }
});
```

I get the following output

```
{ domain: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [] },
  _events: { error: [Function], complete: [Function], pipe: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: 
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     host: 'localhost:8044',
     accept: 'application/json',
     'content-length': 31 },
  callback: [Function],
  readable: true,
  writable: true,
  explicitMethod: true,
  _qs: 
   { request: [Circular],
     lib: { stringify: [Function], parse: [Function] },
     useQuerystring: undefined,
     parseOptions: {},
     stringifyOptions: {} },
  _auth: 
   { request: [Circular],
     hasAuth: false,
     sentAuth: false,
     bearerToken: null,
     user: null,
     pass: null },
  _oauth: { request: [Circular], params: null },
  _multipart: 
   { request: [Circular],
     boundary: 'c3705445-78a6-45b2-80e3-418fffe560ae',
     chunked: false,
     body: null },
  _redirect: 
   { request: [Circular],
     followRedirect: true,
     followRedirects: true,
     followAllRedirects: false,
     allowRedirect: [Function],
     maxRedirects: 10,
     redirects: [],
     redirectsFollowed: 0,
     removeRefererHeader: false },
  _tunnel: 
   { request: [Circular],
     proxyHeaderWhiteList: 
      [ 'accept',
        'accept-charset',
        'accept-encoding',
        'accept-language',
        'accept-ranges',
        'cache-control',
        'content-encoding',
        'content-language',
        'content-location',
        'content-md5',
        'content-range',
        'content-type',
        'connection',
        'date',
        'expect',
        'max-forwards',
        'pragma',
        'referer',
        'te',
        'user-agent',
        'via' ],
     proxyHeaderExclusiveList: [] },
  setHeader: [Function],
  hasHeader: [Function],
  getHeader: [Function],
  removeHeader: [Function],
  localAddress: undefined,
  pool: {},
  dests: [],
  __isRequestRequest: true,
  _callback: [Function],
  uri: 
   { protocol: 'http:',
     slashes: true,
     auth: null,
     host: 'localhost:8044',
     port: '8044',
     hostname: 'localhost',
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/aut',
     path: '/aut',
     href: 'http://localhost:8044/aut' },
  proxy: null,
  tunnel: false,
  setHost: true,
  originalCookieHeader: undefined,
  _disableCookies: true,
  _jar: undefined,
  port: '8044',
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/aut',
  _json: true,
  body: '{"secret":"daha"}',
  httpModule: 
   { IncomingMessage: { [Function: IncomingMessage] super_: [Object] },
     METHODS: 
      [ 'CHECKOUT',
        'CONNECT',
        'COPY',
        'DELETE',
        'GET',
        'HEAD',
        'LOCK',
        'M-SEARCH',
        'MERGE',
        'MKACTIVITY',
        'MKCOL',
        'MOVE',
        'NOTIFY',
        'OPTIONS',
        'PATCH',
        'POST',
        'PROPFIND',
        'PROPPATCH',
        'PURGE',
        'PUT',
        'REPORT',
        'SEARCH',
        'SUBSCRIBE',
        'TRACE',
        'UNLOCK',
        'UNSUBSCRIBE' ],
     OutgoingMessage: { [Function: OutgoingMessage] super_: [Object] },
     ServerResponse: { [Function: ServerResponse] super_: [Object] },
     STATUS_CODES: 
      { '100': 'Continue',
        '101': 'Switching Protocols',
        '102': 'Processing',
        '200': 'OK',
        '201': 'Created',
        '202': 'Accepted',
        '203': 'Non-Authoritative Information',
        '204': 'No Content',
        '205': 'Reset Content',
        '206': 'Partial Content',
        '207': 'Multi-Status',
        '300': 'Multiple Choices',
        '301': 'Moved Permanently',
        '302': 'Moved Temporarily',
        '303': 'See Other',
        '304': 'Not Modified',
        '305': 'Use Proxy',
        '307': 'Temporary Redirect',
        '308': 'Permanent Redirect',
        '400': 'Bad Request',
        '401': 'Unauthorized',
        '402': 'Payment Required',
        '403': 'Forbidden',
        '404': 'Not Found',
        '405': 'Method Not Allowed',
        '406': 'Not Acceptable',
        '407': 'Proxy Authentication Required',
        '408': 'Request Time-out',
        '409': 'Conflict',
        '410': 'Gone',
        '411': 'Length Required',
        '412': 'Precondition Failed',
        '413': 'Request Entity Too Large',
        '414': 'Request-URI Too Large',
        '415': 'Unsupported Media Type',
        '416': 'Requested Range Not Satisfiable',
        '417': 'Expectation Failed',
        '418': 'I\'m a teapot',
        '422': 'Unprocessable Entity',
        '423': 'Locked',
        '424': 'Failed Dependency',
        '425': 'Unordered Collection',
        '426': 'Upgrade Required',
        '428': 'Precondition Required',
        '429': 'Too Many Requests',
        '431': 'Request Header Fields Too Large',
        '500': 'Internal Server Error',
        '501': 'Not Implemented',
        '502': 'Bad Gateway',
        '503': 'Service Unavailable',
        '504': 'Gateway Time-out',
        '505': 'HTTP Version Not Supported',
        '506': 'Variant Also Negotiates',
        '507': 'Insufficient Storage',
        '509': 'Bandwidth Limit Exceeded',
        '510': 'Not Extended',
        '511': 'Network Authentication Required' },
     Agent: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object], defaultMaxSockets: Infinity },
     globalAgent: 
      { domain: [Object],
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        defaultPort: 80,
        protocol: 'http:',
        options: [Object],
        requests: {},
        sockets: {},
        freeSockets: {},
        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
        keepAlive: false,
        maxSockets: Infinity,
        maxFreeSockets: 256 },
     ClientRequest: { [Function: ClientRequest] super_: [Object] },
     request: [Function],
     get: [Function],
     _connectionListener: [Function: connectionListener],
     Server: { [Function: Server] super_: [Object] },
     createServer: [Function],
     Client: [Function: deprecated],
     createClient: [Function: deprecated] },
  agentClass: 
   { [Function: Agent]
     super_: 
      { [Function: EventEmitter]
        EventEmitter: [Circular],
        usingDomains: true,
        defaultMaxListeners: 10,
        init: [Function],
        listenerCount: [Function] },
     defaultMaxSockets: Infinity },
  agent: 
   { domain: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        members: [] },
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     defaultPort: 80,
     protocol: 'http:',
     options: { path: null },
     requests: {},
     sockets: {},
     freeSockets: {},
     keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
     keepAlive: false,
     maxSockets: Infinity,
     maxFreeSockets: 256 } }
test
{ core: { 'test name': { disabled: false, flaky: false, bug: true } } }
```

How do I silent that debug output? I just want to get:

```
test
    { core: { 'test name': { disabled: false, flaky: false, bug: true  } }
```

Comment: Did you run that in the interactive terminal?

Answer (score 0):

When using Node.js in interactive mode (this happens by calling just `node`), the evaluated result of the last statement is automatically printed to the console:

```
> 2+2;
4
> new Object();
{}
> 2+2; 0
0
```

In your case, it was the object representing the request. If you move that code to a JavaScript source file and run it ("node file.js"), that output will no longer occur. For experimentation purposes, assuming that you really want to use Node.js in interactive mode for this, just make the statement return something else. There is more than one approach for this. You can append a shorter value at the end of your code:

```
request({
  "method": "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8044/aut",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({secret: "danzellovestodance"})
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("test"); console.log(response.body);
  }
}); 0 // will print 0, much cleaner
```

or
put the result in a variable:

```
/* variable declarations return undefined */
var req = request({
  "method": "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8044/aut",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({secret: "danzellovestodance"})
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("test"); console.log(response.body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var a= http.request({
 "method": "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:8044/aut",
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({secret: "danzellovestodance"})
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("test"); console.log(response.body);
   }
});
```